# No Scroll on Div inside Another Div

Tags: html, css

How can I get scrolling to work on a div inside of another div?

Here's my sample code and here's [a link to a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pharylon/kQkd9/) showing the result:

**EDIT**: I know I can do scrolling on the outer div, but I don't want to (for instance, the title will scroll away then, and I'd like to keep it there).

```
<body style="background-color:gray">
    <div id="outerDiv" style="background:white;height:200px">
        <h4 class="sideTable">Outer Div</h4>
        <div id="innerDiv" syle="overflow: auto">
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
            Foo<br />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turns out to be scrolling only works if the outer div is set to a height of 100%. So if you don't want to do that, you need another, intervening div? There may be a better way, but this works for me ([fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Pharylon/sCaxB/1/)):

```
<body style="background-color:gray">
    <div id="outerDiv">
        <h4 class="sideTable">Outer Div</h4>
        <div id="holdingDiv">
            <div id="innerDiv">
                Foo1<br />
                Bar1<br />
                Foo2<br />
                Bar2<br />
                Foo3<br />
                Bar3<br />
                Foo4<br />
                Bar4<br />
                Foo5<br />
                Bar5<br />
                Foo6<br />
                Bar6<br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
#outerDiv {
    background:white;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#holdingDiv {
    height:100%;
}


#innerDiv {
    overflow:auto;
    height:100px
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/justtal/kQkd9/3/

just give to: outerDiv

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

scroll will display the scroller even if there is no need.

You can do also "auto"

You also got a mistake:

in #innerDiv
syle => style

Comment: Actually even using `overflow: auto` on the #outerDiv element will work since he gave it an explicit height, and then a scroll bar will only appear if the content is larger than the div.

Answer (score 2):

You were adding `overflow:auto` to the wrong element. Add it to the `#outerDiv`.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/CFZDD/)

```
#outerDiv {
    background:white;
    height:200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Using a value of `auto` is your best option, as the scrollbar will only appear if the height doesn't fix the containing elements. Using `scroll` will always cause the scrollbar to appear regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following CSS:

**1.**

```
#outerDiv{
   overflow:auto; /* Displays scroll only when the contents exceed the containers width or height specified */
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kQkd9/4/)

Also i corrected your html :

Which was - `<div id="innerDiv" syle="overflow: auto">` <kbd>X</kbd>

To - `<div id="innerDiv">`

***Other overflow options***

> **2** overflow:scroll; // *To always display Scroll*
>
> **3** overflow:hidden; // *to hide scroll*
>
> **4** For *only horizontal scroll* use **overflow-x** and for *only vertical scroll* use **overflow-y**